# Get string from plain text through define

Tags: c++, string, macros

So for a task Im trying to to something like this:

```
#define GET_STR 
#define OK
```

and use it like this:

```
GET_STR sample_string OK
```

It should assign to a string the -sample_string- value;
Tried to define `GET_STR` with enum types, or just use the `'#'` but did not seem to work. If the define was type `GET_STR(str)` I could just use `#str` and then assign to a string. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. What's the use case?

Comment: What happens if you do the usual `#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x` `#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)` then `#define GET_STR STRINGIFY(` and `#define OK )`?

Comment: My `#define GET_STR `should not have parenthesis. That's my problem. I have to create something like `#define GET_STR std::string  s= "   `and then `#define OK " ;  `Well, without the "missing terminating character error." :P

Comment: Macros in C (or C++) are a good, but deceptive feature and shouldn't be exploited for the sake of code readability, maintainability and design reasons. What you are trying to achieve is not possible in C(++); if you want to use a macro with a parameter, use parentheses. That's what they are there for. The answers given are great, but what you are trying to produce does not on any level reflect good or valid C(++) code. If this is homework or a work assignment, question its use, validity and the reasons for stating the task.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
#define GET_STR std::string s(
#define OK ); 

std::string sample_string = "hello";
GET_STR sample_string OK
```

or

```
GET_STR "sample_stringggg" OK
```

Comment: Thanks! I want something like that but without " " eg: `GET_STR sample_stringggg OK `

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define GET_STR STRINGIFY(
#define OK )

int main()
{
    printf(GET_STR hello world OK);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. This doesn't work on a line by itself. You always need to wrap it in parantheses. Nevertheless, good macro skill :).